# What's a good temperature for a processor to idle at?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cpu, temperature

I'm running an Intel Core2 Duo T6600 @ 2.20GHz in my Ubuntu laptop, and it runs at around 45 degrees celsius. Is this a good idle temperature? What do most processors run around, temperature-wise?

```
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:      +45.0°C  (high = +90.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)  

coretemp-isa-0001
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 1:      +45.0°C  (high = +90.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The temperatures are fine

Comment: Typical idle temps are probably 35-50 depending on processor model, cooling mechanisms, and amount of dust buildup. If you end up idling at over 50, then your temps under load are going to be hitting the 70's, and soon after that some CPU's start throttling back to try and reduce heat.

Comment: Thanks for the descriptive comment, definitely helps a lot.